# Bootstrap Alignment- with search bar issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create a page with bootstrap device-responsive. I face difficulties in alignment. In the head section of my content, i need to place my heading and then a search bar. i couldnt bootstrap my search bar with animation. can someone help me in this. I have added my program in JSFiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/indhu_velayutham/xpvt214o/339863/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".searchInput").click(function() {
    $(".input").toggleClass("active").focus;
    $(".input-inner").toggleClass("active").focus;
    $(this).toggleClass("animate");
    $(".input-inner").val("");
  });

  $('#clear').click(function() {
    $('.input-inner.active').val('');
  });

});
```

```css
.search_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.searchInput {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 147px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid #00859b;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.input-inner {
  width: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

#clear {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 22px;
  left: -10px;
  top: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#clear:hover {
  background: #00859b;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00859b;
  /*button Background*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 45px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #00859b;
}

.input-inner.active {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 160px;
  right: 150px;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  outline: none;
}

.input.active {
  width: 240px;
  right: 100px;
  height: 60px;
}

.btn.animate {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  /*right: 250px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_wrapper">
  <div class="search-box">
    <div class="input">
      <div id="clear">X</div>
      <input type="text" class="input-inner">
    </div>
    <div class="btn searchButton">
      <img class="searchInput img-responsive" id="searchInput" src="searchImage.png" alt="Search Icon">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it should look.. Can you draw it for us? Also, it the difficult with the alignment or the animation?

Comment: the problem is with the search animation.  After animation the alignment is not fine. can you help me with a proper search animation. Then i will try to put it in the bootstrap.

Comment: I could try, but you have to give me a star point. Can you create a snippet or fiddle and tell how it should look?

Comment: Thank you. Here is the fiddle for this issue http://jsfiddle.net/indhu_velayutham/x3q60teL/13/

on click of the button, the text box should open down the button, not on the exact right. also before button click, the input should be hidden. thank you so much

Comment: `the text box should open down the button` open in which way? I'm trying to understand how it should looks like but ,sorry, there is a mess in this demo.  Why are all the strange position rules? for example: `.input` has both `position: absolute` and  `margin-left: 40%`, `#clear` has `position: relative`. Also, the search button and the input itself are close to each other. Can you clean all the mess to simplify your question? Thanks.